# remove css property with pure js failed

Tags: javascript, css

I tried the following code to remove a property from my css but doesn't work.

```
 document.getElementById("wrap").style.removeProperty('overflow-x');
```

The CSS:

```
#wrap{
overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

When I run the javascript, I get the error `Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: @Scriptable i tried that but didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Describe your problem. Are you getting an error of some sort? If so, post it in your question.

Comment: You are testing this code with an ipad/iphone right?

Comment: @DominatorX the id wrap still contain the overflow-x property

Comment: @KevinBowersox the alert did fired.. yes I'm testing on iphone..

Comment: What is "pure JS"? Is it the same as "plain old JS"? Actually I do know what it means: JS without jQuery. But nevertheless the term "pure JS" somehow sounds very strange to me. In this case, `removeProperty` is not even JavaScript, pure or otherwise; it's the DOM API. So I suppose the title should be "remove css property with DOM API failed", or "remove CSS property with removeProperty failed". Of course, given the specific issue, the actual title should be "removeProperty on element's style does not remove CSS property set via CSS rule, especially if the element does not exist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code posted would remove overflow-x style in the following scenareo:

```
<div id="wrap" style="overflow-x: hidden"></div>
```

CSS applied properties are not applied directly to the style attribute of an element - they are applied at a layer higher.

Effectively, there's nothing to remove on the style property, but you can set a value there instead, which would override the value applied from CSS properties (unless css has `!important` flag specified)

Try this instead:

```
document.getElementById("wrap").style.overflowX = 'visible';
```

---

As your specific scenario is about applying the style based on some browser detection, I suggest the following javascript:

```
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );
if (!is_ios) document.body.className += 'not-ios';
```

With CSS:

```
.not-ios #wrap {
    overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

You could also use `class` "wrap" instead of `id` to make this more re-usable (if required)

Comment: I see this worked but how to remove the css? not style.

Comment: Well your CSS rule targets elements with ID "wrap". You could change/remove the ID of the element, or change the CSS rule to target a specific classname which you remove for iOS devices.

Comment: Then you just remove the class from the element instead. [Some possible methods here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2155787/3180129).

Comment: how to select the id then? since it's .wrap.

Comment: You could loop through elements found using [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) and set the property for each of them. Alternately to avoid a loop and the reliance of timing logic, you could have a single class name (e.g. `not-ios`) added to an element high up in the document (html or body for example) and make your css selector `.not-ios .wrap {...}`, then remove this one class when the browser is detected as an iOS device.

Comment: Updated answer with some more detail about your specific scenario of applying the css rules based on browser detection.

Comment: @JohnSt Please mark as correct answer if this helped you solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: if not ios, apply body with a class name of not-ios? am I right?